# T7 Tagging in Synthetic Biology

Tags: cell-biology, synthetic-biology, purification

What is a T7 tag and can if be used to purify synthesized proteins? Is it charge based like a His tag?

Answer (score 2):

The T7 tag is the first 11 amino acids of the T7 gene 10 protein. Basically, if you engineer a protein with the T7 tag, you've engineered a small, known epitope to the protein of interest which may be detected immunologically. The small size of the epitope reduces the chance it will disrupt the protein's normal function (to which it's tagged). If we look at the affinity purification kit on the [following product page](http://wolfson.huji.ac.il/expression/local/T7tag_affinity.pdf) we can see that specific vectors can be used to express T7-tagged proteins, and an immunoaffinity column can be used to purify the protein of interest. The T7 tag chemical structure is denoted [here](http://www.apexbt.com/t7-tag.html).

Comment: It also allows the discrimination of engineered protein from *in vivo* expressed proteins and you don't have to make specific antibodies for each protein but use antibodies against the t7 tag instead.

Comment: What makes it different from the [FLAG-Tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAG-tag)? (Besides sequence of course)

Comment: I don't have any data on how each epitope may affect stability or what have you, but it generally follows that whether it be T7, FLAG, HA or Myc etc. they're just method of recognition through the use of an anti-tag antibody (anti-HA, anti-FLAG, etc.) in immunoassay.